# How to update UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have custom UITableViewCell with property `count: Int?`. According to this property I render amount of UITextFields. (I.g. `count == 1` --> one UITextField, `count == 2` --> two UITextFields).

Later when some event happens I want to set new value for this label. Here what I do:

Inside my UIViewController:

```
@objc func onDidReceiveEvent(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let count = notification.object as? Int else { return }
        guard let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)) as? MyCustomCell else { return }

        cell.count = count
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        // I also tried self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I put breakpoint inside of `override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` and I see that the cell is being updated after this block of code, but the property `count` is not updated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
```

is called once when the cell is created , then the cell is dequeued you need to add a

```
func configure(_ count:Int)
```

inside your cell custom class and call it from `cellForRowAt` or refresh here

```
guard let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)) as? MyCustomCell else { return }  
cell.configure(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

- In the controller create a property `count`

  ```
  var count = 0 // or another default value
  ```
- In `cellForRow` assign the value of `count` to the `count` property of the cell

  ```
  if indexPath.row == 2 {
     cell.count = count
  }
  ```
- In `onDidReceiveEvent` update `count` and reload the row

  ```
  @objc func onDidReceiveEvent(_ notification: Notification) {
      guard let count = notification.object as? Int else { return }
      self.count = count
      self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without knowing how your code looks like but I assume that your `UITableViewDataSource` isn't up to date as `onDidReceiveEvent()` gets invoked.

So if my assumption is correct, the only thing you need to do is making sure that your `UITableViewDataSource` is updated before you call `reloadRows()`:

```
@objc func onDidReceiveEvent(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let count = notification.object as? Int else { return }
    // Make sure that the dataSource of self.tableView is updated before you update the cell
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}
```